# looping load data from database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, for-loop

I want to ask: why when I load the my program it doesn't appear?

My program is when I clicked my button it will load from all component from my database. I'm using loop from method `getRow();`. Strangely there was no error in netbeans but the picture didn't want to display. No error in SQL I think. How to fix it?

```
public void loaddata(){
try{
    ImageIcon img;
    koneksi_db();
    java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * FROM component where UsernameID ='"+jLabel5.getText()+"' ");    // query for load as username login

    for (int i=1; i<rs.getRow(); i++){   // loading data using loop from get row
        rs.getRowId(i);
        JLabel draggy = new JLabel();
        String imagePath =  rs.getString("source");
        int x = rs.getInt("coordinatX");
        int y = rs.getInt("coordinatY");
        String nama = rs.getString("UniqueID");
        img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imagePath));
            draggy.setIcon(img);
            draggy.setText(nama);
            this.add(draggy);
            draggy.setBounds(x, y, 70, 70); //calling dragy (jlabel) in frame.
    }
    }catch(Exception e){

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error in sql");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the container using a layout manager?  Have you tried repainting the container?  Have you verified the location of the component?  Try using `ImageIO.read` instead of `ImageIcon(URL)`

Comment: sure.i've verified my location of the component.when i try change to `img = new ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(imagePath));` i got error cannot find symbol read

Comment: Did you add the import statement for `javax.imageio.ImageIO`?

Comment: yes i've been import javax.imageio.ImageIO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is not running, because `i<rs.getRow()` is always `false`.

Quoting javadoc of [`ResultSet.getRow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow%28%29):

> Retrieves the current row number. The first row is number 1, the second number 2, and so on. [...] Returns the current row number; **0 if there is no current row**

Since you never retrieved a row, it returns `0`.

Quoting javadoc of [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A `ResultSet` object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The `next` method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns `false` when there are no more rows in the `ResultSet` object, it can be used in a `while` loop to iterate through the result set.

So, you write your loop like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    // call rs.getXxx methods to retrieve column values
}
```

Also, **DO NOT** build a SQL statement by using string concatenation with a string entered by a user. That will leave you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, allowing a user to **steal or delete all your data**.

Instead, use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM component WHERE UsernameID = ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement()) {
    stmt.setString(1, jLabel5.getText());
    try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            // code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for suggest.but can you give me example from my script to load like my script?without for.

Comment: That *is* an example from your script. Replace the `// code here` with your code, starting with `JLabel draggy = ...` and ending with `draggy.setBounds(...)`.